# Make swimming boids avoid/flee a predator object

Tags: particles

I have a blender cube, emitting sardines. The sardines seek a goal, a curve, to which I have attached a force field.

I have added a sphere... and then I go nuts. Before 2.7, I was able to make the boids avoid a "predator".... but I seem unable to do so now.  The Avoid | Object brain element seems not to be causing my sardines to avoid my sphere... which I have tried both with and without a force itself.

See attached file. I would like the sardines to scatter as the sphere -- or some object or empty or something -- passes through it.  Worse... I have done it before and my older file does not work.

So, I welcome guidance to (current) docs or an answer: what do I need to do to get my boids to avoid the Sphere of Death?

[image]

Comment: Don't know why, but removing and adding the rules again fixed it in your file.